# Respect memory setting in manifest after having run cf scale command

Tags: cloud-foundry

We have an application deployed to Cloud Foundry that:

- has a memory setting in the manifest that it is deployed with
- has had the `cf scale` command run against it to set its memory to something else

When we re-deploy the application, the new instances are created with the memory size specified by the `cf scale` command and not the manifest. This makes sense.

However, we would like to know if there is some command that can be run or maybe a setting that can be set on the `cf push` command that causes the memory setting in the manifest to be respected in favor of whatever value was last set by the `cf scale` command.

Comment: When you do a `cf push`, the memory value set in the manifest or by the `-m` flag should always be respected, and any previous setting (set by `cf scale` or otherwise) be overridden. When you say "re-deploy the application", are you doing something else than `cf push`?

Comment: We're using the cf-blue-green-deploy plugin (linked to below). It handles the actual push to cf itself. We are able to specify a manifest file for it to use. I am not sure how exactly it uses the values contained within the manifest. Perhaps there is no good way to use the plugin as is and also scale memory through the manifest. https://github.com/bluemixgaragelondon/cf-blue-green-deploy#how-to-use

Comment: If you want to debug more then you could try enabling trace logging with the cf cli and see what requests are being sent to the API.  Or just `cf scale` it back to the required value.  That will cause the app to be restarted though.